# Loop in the same script code to two specific tabs that opens up the one with the recent edit

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I don't really have knowledge on scripts, and I only went so far by researching for some time in getting the specific codes I need. But I don't think I can do this by myself, I need help.

I had tried different codes that might suit my needs, and finally have found this scrip[t code/s:

```
    function onOpen() {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde 5 March 2020
  //  - add sheetName, dateColumn
  //  - use value.getTime to check that dateColumn contains dates
  //  - find today instead of tomorrow
  //  - use descriptive variable names
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=32396362
  // version 1.0, written by AD:AM 15 May 2019
  //  - initial version
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6074864?msgid=6156095

  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  var sheetName = 'sheetname';
  var dateColumn = 2; // A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).getTime();
  for (var i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][dateColumn - 1];
    if (value.getTime && value.getTime() >= today) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, dateColumn).activate();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried copying that code and renaming the (sheet name) to the 2 tabs I needed to have that function, though it only works one or the other. I need it to work for both of them. This script opens up to the current date, and I want it to work on both tabs, since the 2 tabs have different user assigned.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R_mntozMyOL-jYJUU0o38IgiHc5GbrdyWMn6Wb3UHZc/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy of my sheets for your reference.

Please help me on this one, for I really can't understand much about how to read codes, I only research.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome. You have shared your spreadsheet (good!) and some code (very good!), but you haven't really explained what you're trying to do and why, and what part of the code isn't working as you expect. Do yourself a favour; make it easy for users to help you - describe your scenario , what you're trying to achieve and why your solution isn't working. If you can't do that much, then you shouldn't expect that many users will think it is worthwhile to open your spreadsheet and read your code - they just won't bother.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz . I apologize for providing an unclear explanation to what I really wanted to happen. To summarize it all, I want to enable the script above to  two specific sheets. So whenever I edit one of the sheets, when refreshed, or when I open it again, it jumps to the current date in the sheet. For a better understanding, here is a  [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lpCQqRBq4TUvWs15J8bwtjmjM5xnkg7k) I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andres notes, activating the sheet that was edited most recently requires that the script monitors edit events. The "jump to cell by date" function should however not be run from the onEdit(e) function, because that would cause the selection to jump every time the spreadsheet is edited.

See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=33126935 for a solution that has a separate `saveLastEditedCellLocationPerSheet_()` function to run from the onEdit(e) function. Here's a copy of the essential bits:

```
/**
* Saves the location of the edited cell on each sheet,
* and the name of the sheet that was last edited.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function saveLastEditedCellLocationPerSheet_(e) {
  if (!e.range || JSON.stringify(e.range) === '{}') {
    return;
  }
  var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var propKeyNames = getPropKeyNames_();
  var propertiesToUpdate = {};
  propertiesToUpdate[propKeyNames.lastEditedSheet] = sheetName;
  propertiesToUpdate[propKeyNames.lastEditedCellOnSheetPrefix + sheetName] = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var propStore = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  propStore.setProperties(propertiesToUpdate);
}

/**
* Gets the property key names to use to access the properties.
*
* @return {Object} The property key names to use to access the properties.
*/
function getPropKeyNames_() {
  return {
    lastEditedSheet: 'lastEditedSheet',
    lastEditedCellOnSheetPrefix: 'lastEditedCellOnSheet_',
    lastEditedCellOnSheetRegex: /^lastEditedCellOnSheet_/,
  };
}
```

Cheers --Hyde

Comment: Thank you Hyde. Really helped me a lot. This is the exact function I was looking for. Glad I found those threads, and this site. Cheers all!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use more than one `onOpen()` trigger per document.  As the logic in your code is already working for one sheet, you could change the way you're getting the `sheet` variable, from this:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

To this:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

The [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) method will retrieve the sheet being opened or edited in the moment.

You need to use an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger besides your `onOpen()` trigger to activate the cell when editing the sheet as well. I tested this code and worked successfully:

```
function onOpen() {
  activateLastDateCell();
}

function onEdit() {
  activateLastDateCell();
}

function activateLastDateCell() {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde 5 March 2020
  //  - add sheetName, dateColumn
  //  - use value.getTime to check that dateColumn contains dates
  //  - find today instead of tomorrow
  //  - use descriptive variable names
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=32396362
  // version 1.0, written by AD:AM 15 May 2019
  //  - initial version
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6074864?msgid=6156095

  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  //var sheetName = '(Ian) Hulog - Hulog 2020';
  var dateColumn = 2; // A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).getTime();
  for (var i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][dateColumn - 1];
    if (value.getTime && value.getTime() >= today) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, dateColumn).activate();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andres, thank you for trying to help me, and for taking your time to fix my problem. It does jumps to the current date, though as Hyde said, it really do jumps every time the spreadsheet is edited. I truly am happy receiving answers to the problems that bugged me for nights. It just happens that I found a better answer that fits to my needs. Thank you :)